# How can I change an animated sprite's images per second from script?

Tags: animation, godot

Consider an `AnimatedSprite` with an animation of 9 `.png` files and a setting of 5 images per second. How can I change the number of images per second from script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to vary the speed of the animation is setting the [`speed_scale`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_animatedsprite.html#class-animatedsprite-property-speed-scale) attribute of the `AnimatedSprite` node. Thus, get a reference to the node and set its `speed_scale` (it is a factor). For example:

```
$AnimatedSprite.speed_scale = 1.5
```

---

It is also possible to access the [`frames`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_animatedsprite.html#class-animatedsprite-property-frames) attribute, which gives you a [`SpriteFrames`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_spriteframes.html) object. Then you can get the animation speed in frames per second by calling [`get_animation_speed`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_spriteframes.html#class-spriteframes-method-get-animation-speed). For example:

```
var fps = $AnimatedSprite.frames.get_animation_speed("Animation")
```

Now, let us assume we want to set a particular number of frames per second, we could use it to compute the desired factor:

```
var sprite = $AnimatedSprite
var desired_fps = 7
var actual_fps = sprite.frames.get_animation_speed("Animation")
var factor = desired_fps / actual_fps
sprite.speed_scale = factor
```

Alternatively, we could set the animation speed in frames per second by calling [`set_animation_speed`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_spriteframes.html#class-spriteframes-method-set-animation-speed), the parameters are the animation name and the speed you want. For example:

```
var desired_fps = 7
$AnimatedSprite.frames.set_animation_speed("Animation", desired_fps)
```

Note, however, that if you modify the animation this way, it will change the speed of the animation anywhere it is used. Which is why, it is recommended to use `speed_scale` to modify the speed for a single `AnimatedSprite`.